# System could not be found, Xamarin.Forms not found

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    Beer Garden1    C:\Users\henry\source\repos\Beer Garden1\Beer Garden1\Beer Garden1\ViewModel\LoginViewModel.cs  3   Active

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   Beer Garden1    C:\Users\henry\source\repos\Beer Garden1\Beer Garden1\Beer Garden1\ViewModel\LoginViewModel.cs  7   Active

I am currently getting the above errors and unsure as to why. I have spent hours looking through stack overflow and google and nothing is working,

Clean solution, rebuild, build reload has not worked.

Repairing visual studio has not worked

Im stumped please anything to help will be appreciated!

```
using Beer_Garden1.Services;
using Beer_Garden1.View;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Beer_Garden1.ViewModel
{
    public class LoginViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public Command cmdLogin { get; set;  }
    public Command cmdCreateAccount { get; set; }
    public Command cmdForgotPassword { get; set; }
    public Command cmdSetting { get; set; }

    ILoginService ilog = DependencyService.Get<ILoginService>();

    public LoginViewModel()
    {
        cmdLogin = new Command(gotoMainPage);
        cmdCreateAccount = new Command(gotoCreateAccount);
        cmdForgotPassword = new Command(gotoForgotPassword);
        cmdSetting = new Command(gotoSetting);
        
    }

    private void gotoSetting(object obj)
    {
        App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new SettingPage());
    }

    private void gotoForgotPassword(object obj)
    {
        App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new ForgotPasswordPage());
    }

    private void gotoCreateAccount(object obj)
    {
        App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new CreateAccountPage());
    }

    private void gotoMainPage(object obj)
    {
        if (ilog.login(UserName, Password))
        {
            App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
        }
        else
        {
            LoginMessage = "Please enter a valid user name and password!";
            TurnLoginMessage = true;
        }

    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    private string userName;
    public string UserName
    { get 
        { 
            return userName; 
        } 
        set 
        { 
            userName = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("UserName"));
        } 
    }

    private string password;
    public string Password
    {
        get
        {
            return password;
        }
        set
        {
            password = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Password"));
        }
    }

    private string loginMessage;
    public string LoginMessage
    {
        get
        {
            return LoginMessage;
        } set
        {
            loginMessage = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LoginMessage"));
        }
    }

    private bool turnLoginMessage = false;
    public bool TurnLoginMessage
    {
        get
        {
            return turnLoginMessage;
        }
        set
        {
            turnLoginMessage = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TurnLoginMessage"));
        }
    }
}
```

}

_________________________________________________________________________________UPDATE::

I managed to fix the package source issue and it is now accepting xamarin.forms and system but is throwing erros under `using System.Collections.Generic;`
`using System.ComponentModel;`
`using System.Text;`

When restoring NuGet Packages I get the following error

```
NU1603: Beer Garden1.iOS depends on Xamarin.Forms (>= 4.8.0.1451) but Xamarin.Forms 4.8.0.1451 was not found. An approximate best match of Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2012 was resolved.
NU1102: Unable to find package System.Numerics.Vectors with version (>= 4.5.0)
  - Found 2 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [ Nearest version: 4.1.1 ]
NU1603: Beer Garden1.Android depends on Xamarin.Essentials (>= 1.5.3.2) but Xamarin.Essentials 1.5.3.2 was not found. An approximate best match of Xamarin.Essentials 1.6.1 was resolved.
NU1603: Beer Garden1.Android depends on Xamarin.Forms (>= 4.8.0.1451) but Xamarin.Forms 4.8.0.1451 was not found. An approximate best match of Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2012 was resolved.
NU1102: Unable to find package System.Numerics.Vectors with version (>= 4.5.0)
  - Found 2 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [ Nearest version: 4.1.1 ]
NuGet package restore failed. Please see Error List window for detailed warnings and errors.
Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.1797576
```

Comment: did you restore NuGet packages?

Comment: `using System;` <- that is will add `System` to your project to be used. Same thing with Xamarin. When it says `Are you missing a directive or assembly reference?` listen to that. It means you're not referencing something your project is trying to use.

Comment: I restored NuGet packeges and it didnt do anything also I am using both xamarin.forms and system

Comment: Edit made to show you the file, This error is not just appearing on this file but across the entire project, also this error persists on new projects

Comment: @Jason this is the error i recieve when trying to restore NuGet packages `Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: Failed to retrieve information about 'NETStandard.Library' from remote source 'https://packagesource/FindPackagesById()?id='NETStandard.Library'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
`

Comment: that sounds like your nuget config is messed up

Comment: @Jason Is there a way to fix this, I am unsure how. I am pretty new to all of this

Comment: Probably.  You should look at the nuget config settings for your system.  "https://packagesource" does not sound like a correct value.

Comment: @Jason my NuGet.Config contains this line  `<add key="Package source" value="https://packagesource" />`

Comment: @Jason I managed to fix the package source issue and it is now accepting xamarin.forms and system but is throwing erros under `using System.Collections.Generic;`
`using System.ComponentModel;`
`using System.Text;`

Comment: "throwing errors" is not a useful description of the problem

Comment: @Jason Apologies, The error is the same as before its a CS0234 Error on all 3

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue in the end, I deleted the NuGet folder from `%appdata%` This was then recreated back with its defaults on VS startup and simply I had to run a NuGet Package restore and it removed all 98 of my errors and 13 of my warnings.

I hope this comes in handy for anyone running the same issue as it was hard for me to find a solution myself online.

Thank you everyone for your help!